# Reach User Defined Build Settings inside exportOptionsPlist

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild

I have a project which consists of different targets for different build environments. I'm getting IPA file on Jenkins with `xcodebuild`. I want to define one exportOptionsPlist file and assign a different variable for different targets. For example, for `method`, Dev target should have `development` and Prod target should have `app-store`. For achieving this I'm defining `User-Defined` settings in Build Settings.

P.S: Every target has only Debug and Release options and every target has IPA_EXPORT_METHOD.
[image]

My problem is that I'm getting below error when trying to get the IPA (**Reading IPA_EXPORT_METHOD from the ExportOptionsPlist file**):

> Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {app-store, ad-hoc, enterprise, development, validation}, but found ${IPA_EXPORT_METHOD}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {app-store, ad-hoc, enterprise, development, validation}, but found ${IPA_EXPORT_METHOD}}

How can I get the archive:

```
$ xcodebuild -workspace CLI.xcworkspace -scheme CLI -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/build/CLI.xcarchive
```

How can I get the IPA:

```
$ xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/build/CLI.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build
```

Export Options Plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>export</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>${IPA_EXPORT_METHOD}</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.iamdeveloper.myproject.dev</key>
        <string>My Provision File</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iPhone Developer</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;thin-for-all-variants&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**EDIT:** I can define different exportOptionsPlists for different targets. This solves my problem but I want to achieve it with one plist file.

Comment: so the question is about accessing the user-defined setting variable in your code?

Comment: for IPA_Export_Method you don't have defined method for a production environment.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Nope not in the code, reaching from the plist file.

Comment: Any solution found for user defined settings option with one plist file? I would like to do the same...

Comment: Yes. You can create a pre-build script and edit export options plist file via this variable just before getting build

Comment: @EmreÖnder, so variables are not automatically resolved, like they are for other plist files?